# php script that reloads the page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having difficulty with pages that does not show the updated data immediately
Here's my current one:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("hospital", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t2");

 echo"<br>";
 echo"<big>All In Patients</big>";
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Pnum</th>
<th>HospNum</th>
<th>RoomNum</th>
<th>LastName</th>
<th>FirstName</th>
<th>MidName</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>TelNum</th>
<th>Stat</th>
<th>Nurse</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['PNUM'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['HOSPNUM'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ROOMNUM'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LASTNAME'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['FIRSTNAME'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['MIDNAME'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['ADDRESS'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['TELNUM'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['STAT'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['NURSE'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>

<form>
<input type="button"  class='type_button'  value="Print" onClick="window.print();" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you know of any workaround that could make the code above updated? Because when I update the data and then load the code above. It will only show the previous data which has not been updated yet. You will have to right click and refresh the page in order to see the effects.

Comment: you should do UPDATE in your code above the SELECT, then it should work, if not then problem is somewhere else

Comment: not a cache problem,Ive tried the code below but wont work

Comment: did my answer not solve your problem afterall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set cache headers.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Or maybe you are fetching cached data from the MySQL?

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM t2
```